# Access to stage timing through API

Tags: jenkins-workflow

In the Stage View plugin, we can see on each of the stages a timestamp that displays number of seconds for the stage, and number of seconds spent waiting within that stage. This is kind of interesting data but I haven't figure out where we may be able to access it outside of the display on the single pipeline. If we want to use these times in our own metrics program, say to measure trends over multiple pipelines and/or projects, is it accessible externally somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the existent JSON API: `http://[JENKINS_HOST]/job/test/[BUILD_NUMBER]/wfapi/describe`

There is timing information in the response.

Comment: Just beware that this API was built for use from the UI and may change with new releases.